# Android. TransitionDrawable: how make animation forward and back

Tags: android

I have a simple sample for TransitionDrawable, when I click on ImageView one picture goes to second picture. But how on next click go back from second picture to one?

image.setImageDrawable(mTransition);
mTransition.startTransition(1000);

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea,it may work for you.

take another transition animation xml file and reverse the images
take a vriable

```
int v=2;
```

and inside onClick,

```
public void onClick(){
if(v%2==0){
image.setImageDrawable(mTransition1);
mTransition1.startTransition(1000);
v++;
}
else{
image.setImageDrawable(mTransition2);
mTransition2.startTransition(1000);
v++;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I find myself another solution with reverseTransition method and your code:     @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  image.setImageDrawable(mTransition); 
    
  if(count%2 == 0){
   mTransition.startTransition(1000);
   count++;
   }
   else{
   mTransition.reverseTransition(1000);
   count++;
   }
 }